SwiftUI Bool state not updated or incorrect
Working with Xcode 15 on the latest available version of macOS 14,
I have a very simple SwiftUI form whose Save button is supposed to be disabled only as long as both of the form fields are filled in:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct AddToDoScreen: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var priority: Int?
    
    private var isFormValid: Bool {
        !name.isEmpty && priority != nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            TextField("Priority", value: $priority, format: .number)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add ToDo")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button("Dismiss") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    
                    guard let priority = priority else { return }
                    
                    let toDo = ToDo(name: name, priority: priority)
                    context.insert(toDo)
                    
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    
                    dismiss()
                    
                }.disabled(!isFormValid)
            }
        }
    }
}


GitHub link of the project:
https://github.com/atilsamancioglu/iOS50-SwiftDataToDo
Is there anything wrong with my code or is this another Apple bug? Is there anything I can do as a fix or workaround?

The second text field expects a number. "Normal" is not a number, so priority is nil.

Do you expect the save button to still be enabled, even when priority is nil? The save button will not do anything and will return after hitting guard let priority = priority else { return }

I ran your code and giving a number as priority enables the save button as expected. This question should be closed as a type or similar.

You need to type in a number in the second text field since you used format: .number. If it can't parse the text as a number then it sets your Int? state to nil and thats why the button does not enable.
FYI I looked at your project and it's best if you switch from sheet(isPresented:) to sheet(item:). In the button action create the new model object, store it as an @State var item that you use as the sheet's binding. Then in the AddToDoScreen bind your text fields to that object instead of those independent states.
